# Use different sessions for the same domain

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have built 2 web applications in Yii2 , but they are work in local network so if user need to visit the first app he will go for example 
    `http://localhost/adv/web/index.php`
and for the second app 
    `http://localhost/arch/web/index.php`

The problem is:
for example in first app userid=2 for user `john`,
the second app userid=2 for user `doe`.

If the user in the first app has logged in and have ID=2 `john`, if he visit the other app he will take the session of other user with ID=2 for other user `doe`

I need to force user to login if he visit other app.

Comment: You'll want to restrict *the path of the cookies*, so cookies from one app aren't used in the other.

Comment: You can use `session_name` before `session_start` eg. session_name('adv');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set different session name for different apps in their config. For exaple for `adv`:

```
'session' => [
    'name' => 'session_adv',
],
```

And for `arch`:

```
'session' => [
    'name' => 'session_arch',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change var names in session, for example if session like this

```
[ 'userid' => 2 ]
```

than you can save userid in session by another name, like this

```
[ 
  'adv_userid' => 2,
  'arch_user_id' => 4
]
```

or if it hard for you to change everywhere name, you can save in session the

> user_id + (password or login)

if he logged  in for adv app, his login will not work with arch app